# yamm navbar bootstrap with flex

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

i use yamm in bootstrap, but i need to make it flex so each list will have same spaces to another, and if i want to add another li in the future it wont mess the space between them, but every time i use display:flex. it wont affect anything. so can you guys help?

heres my code

```css
.yamm .nav,
.yamm .collapse,
.yamm .dropup,
.yamm .dropdown {
  position: static;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu {
  left: auto;
  top: 110% ;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu .yamm-content {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu .yamm-content .links li a {
  padding: 8px 0px;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: #555;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'FjallaOneRegular';
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu li {
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #3D3D3D;
  line-height: 26px ;
  text-transform: none ;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.yamm .dropdown-menu li a:focus {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu .text {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 73px;
}
.yamm .dropdown.yamm-fw .dropdown-menu {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
 .header-nav .yamm .dropdown-menu {
    background: #fff;
  }
.yamm .dropdown-menu.pages {
    padding: 10px 37px;
  }
.yamm .dropdown-menu .title:hover,
.yamm .dropdown-menu .title:focus {
  color: #12cca7;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.yamm .dropdown-menu li a:focus {
  color: #12cca7;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu {
  border-top-color: #12cca7;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-nav animate-dropdown" style="background-color:#3498db">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="yamm navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button data-target="#mc-horizontal-menu-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-bg-class">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mc-horizontal-menu-collapse">
 <div class="nav-outer">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active dropdown yamm-fw">
    <a href="home.html" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='#fff'">Home</a><!-- LOOPING -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li>
      <div class="yamm-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-md-12'>
                
                   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <h2 class="title">Computer</h2>
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li><a href="#" >Lenovo</a></li><!-- LOOPING -->
                            <li><a href="#" >Microsoft </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >Fuhlen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >Longsleeves</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <h2 class="title">Camera</h2>
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li><a href="#" >Fuhlen</a></li><!-- LOOPING -->
                            <li><a href="#" >Lenovo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >Microsoft </a></li>                   
                            <li><a href="#" >Longsleeves</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <h2 class="title">Apple Store</h2>
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li><a href="#" >Longsleeves</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >Fuhlen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >Lenovo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >Microsoft </a></li>                                       
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <h2 class="title">Smart Phone</h2>
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li><a href="#" 
   >Microsoft </a></li> <!-- LOOPING -->
                            <li><a href="#">Longsleeves</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">"Fuhlen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lenovo</a></li>
                                   
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->

                    </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
   
        <!-- ============================================== WIDE PRODUCTS ============================================== -->
        

<!-- ============================================== WIDE PRODUCTS : END ============================================== -->
 
</div><!-- /.yamm-content -->     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>


   <li class="dropdown">
    
    <a href="category.html" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='#fff'" >Electronics <!-- LOOPING -->
       <span class="menu-label hot-menu hidden-xs">hot</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown hidden-sm">
    
    <a href="category.html" >Television
        <span class="menu-label new-menu hidden-xs">new</span>
    </a>
   </li>

   <li class="dropdown hidden-sm">
    <a href="category.html" >Smart Phone</a>
   </li>

   <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="contact.html" >Contact</a>
   </li>
   
   
   
  </ul><!-- /.navbar-nav -->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>    
 </div><!-- /.nav-outer -->
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->


            </div><!-- /.nav-bg-class -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar-default -->
    </div><!-- /.container-class -->

</div><!-- /.header-nav -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use flex, you should add the `display: flex` to the parent element.

You may do it simply like this ( I have intentionally left CSS definition for  `.col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3` empty, to show you there is no special need to define a CSS rule for the flex child, until you have a specific style need ):

```css
.col-md-12{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3{

}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-12'>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <h2 class="title">Computer</h2>
  <ul class="links">
   <li><a href="#" >Lenovo</a></li><!-- LOOPING -->
   <li><a href="#" >Microsoft </a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Fuhlen</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Longsleeves</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <h2 class="title">Camera</h2>
  <ul class="links">
   <li><a href="#" >Fuhlen</a></li><!-- LOOPING -->
   <li><a href="#" >Lenovo</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Microsoft </a></li>                   
   <li><a href="#" >Longsleeves</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <h2 class="title">Apple Store</h2>
  <ul class="links">
   <li><a href="#" >Longsleeves</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Fuhlen</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Lenovo</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Microsoft </a></li>                                       
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <h2 class="title">Smart Phone</h2>
  <ul class="links">
   <li><a href="#">Microsoft </a></li> <!-- LOOPING -->
   <li><a href="#">Longsleeves</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">"Fuhlen</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lenovo</a></li>     
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```